# Is there a way to make a fixed variable in a plot?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.figure(1) #elegimos figura en la que plotearemos
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10]) 

n = 10 

pos = (20 * np.random.sample(n*2) - 10).reshape(n, 2)
vel = (0.5 * np.random.normal(size=n*2)).reshape(n, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(n) + 100

colors = np.random.sample([n, 4])
circles = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker="o", s=sizes, c=colors)

for i in range(30):
    pos = pos + vel#se actualiza posiscion de pelotas a traves de velocidad
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10      
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce] 
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

I wanted to make an animated plot that had the same initial position for the balls everytime i run the program. But the velocity had to change for each ball when i run it. Is there a way to make this easily without changing the code so much?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the numpy random generator seed as follow:

```
np.random.seed(15)
```

You can use the seed of your choice. But each time you will run the code using the same seed, the same numbers will be generated and your balls will appear at the same position.

Comment: Is there a way to make this code work only for the position?, I wanted the velocity to change each time i run the program, but it stays the same when i use random.seed